# Failed to save mailbox : Failed to open PID file

Tags: postfix

I am using Virtualmin, My email are not working fine server not receive any emails and all bounced email trap in email queue.
When I Try to "Login to Usermin" it show following error.
Failed to save mailbox : Failed to open PID file

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check service usermin status this error comes when usermin service stoped.